# How does SQL estimate the number of rows in a less than < Predicate

Tags: sql-server-2016, statistics, database-internals, cardinality-estimates

I have been doing some testing to try to better understand how SQL Server uses a histogram to estimate the number of rows that will match an equality predicate and also a < or > predicate

Given I am using the [AdventureWorks2016 OLTP database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n39vO.png)

If can understand SQL Server's estimation process for = and > predicates:

```
/* update stats with fullscan first */    
UPDATE STATISTICS Production.TransactionHistory WITH FULLSCAN
```

Then I can see the histogram for the column `TransactionHistory.Quantity`

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (
    'Production.TransactionHistory', 
    'Quantity')
```

The below screenshot is the top end of the histogram where I have run my tests:

[image]

The following query will estimate 6 rows as the value in the predicate is a RANGE_HI_KEY so uses the EQ_ROWS for that bucket:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Production.TransactionHistory
WHERE   Quantity = 2863
```

The following will estimate 1.36 rows as it is not a RANGE_HI_KEY so uses the AVG_RANGE_ROWS for the bucket it falls in:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Production.TransactionHistory
WHERE   Quantity = 2862
```

The following "greater than" query will estimate 130 rows which appears to be the sum of the RANGE_ROWS and the EQ_ROWS for all the buckets with a RANGE_HI_KEY > 2863

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Production.TransactionHistory
WHERE   Quantity > 2863
```

A similar query below, but the value is not a RANGE_HI_KEY in the histogram. SQL Server again estimates 130 and appears to use the same method as above

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Production.TransactionHistory
WHERE   Quantity > 2870
```

This all makes sense up to now so my testing moved onto a "less than" query

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Production.TransactionHistory
WHERE   Quantity < 490
```

for this query, SQL Server estimates 109,579 rows but I can't work out where it has got that from:

RANGE_HI_KEY + RANGE_ROWS of all buckets up to and including RANGE_HI_KEY 470 = 109,566 so we are 11 short somewhere.

How does SQL Server use the histogram to estimate the number of rows that will be returned by a "less than" predicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> for this query, SQL Server estimates **109,579 rows** but I can't work out where it has got that from:
>
> RANGE_HI_KEY + RANGE_ROWS of all buckets up to and including RANGE_HI_KEY 470 = **109,566** so we are 11 short somewhere.

You're **13 short**, not 11: 109,579 - 109,566 = 13.

The general idea, as shown in my [related answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/169384/1192) is to use linear interpolation within the partial step, assuming uniformity.

In your case:

[image: histogram fragment]

So the question is how many of those 23 `RANGE_ROWS` do we expect to match the predicate `< 490` when they are assumed to be distributed uniformly within the histogram step with `RANGE_HI_KEY` 500:

```
DECLARE
    @ARR float = 23e0 / 6e0, -- AVG_RANGE_ROWS
    @DRR float = 6e0,        -- DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS
    @PR float = 490 - 470,   -- predicate range
    @SR float = 499 - 470    -- whole step range (excluding high key)

SELECT (@DRR - 1) * ((@PR - 1) / @SR) / ((@SR - 1) / @SR) * @ARR;
```

This computation gives **13.00595**.

The `-1` factors account for using `<` which is assumed to exclude a `DISTINCT_RANGE_ROW` row. When `<=` is used, that row is assumed to match the predicate.

The whole thing is a modification of applying the fraction of the range you are asking for versus the range covered by the histogram step. Without excluding the unmatched value, it would be simply `@PR/@SR`.